# Why the probability greater than 100% when I use Naive Bayesian for classification

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes

I use **Naive Bayesian** to train a dataSet:

```
weather     temperature humidity    windspeed   Y/N?

rain        cool        normal      strong      N
sunny       hot         high        strong      N
sunny       hot         high        weak        N
sunny       mild        high        weak        N
sunny       cool        normal      weak        Y
overcast    hot         normal      weak        Y
rain        mild        normal      weak        Y
rain        cool        normal      weak        Y
overcast    hot         high        weak        Y
sunny       mild        normal      strong      Y
overcast    mild        high        strong      Y
```

**Table for count:** 
[image]

```
count(Y) = 7,count(N) = 4
```

Table for probability:
[image]

```
P(Y)=7/11, P(N)=4/11
```

**Now, there is a new data:**

```
overcast  hot   normal   weak
```

I will predict the classification for this data, I compute the probability of **P(Y|overcast, hot, normal, weak)** first:

```
P(Y|overcast, hot, normal, weak)  
= P(overcast, hot, normal, weak|Y)P(Y) / P(overcast, hot, normal, weak) 
= P(overcast|Y)P(hot|Y)P(normal|Y)P(weak|Y)P(Y) / P(overcast)P(hot)P(normal)P(weak)
= (3/7 * 2/7 * 5/7 * 5/7 * 7/11)  /  (3/11 * 4/11 * 6/11 * 7/11)
= (1050/26411) / (504/14641)
= 0.039756 / 0.034423
= 1.154925
```

Why the probability(1.154925) greater than 1?

How can I get right probability in this case by using Naive Bayesian?

Comment: What if you'll use the 'maximum a posteriori hypothesis' this was you don't have to divide by the 'evidence' and your max result will tell you if it's likely to be Y or N.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues here:

1. You do not actually need to divide by `P(overcast, hot, normal, weak)` for classification as you just need to see whether `P(overcast, hot, normal, weak | Y) P(Y)` is bigger or smaller than `P(overcast, hot, normal, weak | N) P(N)`
2. If you do divide then your calculation of `P(overcast, hot, normal, weak)` should be something like `P(overcast, hot, normal, weak | Y) P(Y) + P(overcast, hot, normal, weak | N) P(N)` if you want your posterior probabilities to add up to $1$ (this is the direct answer to your question title - neither probability will then exceed $1$)
3. You have small sample sizes and in particular all four observed cases of `overcast` are associated with `Y`.  That is going to make `P(overcast | N)` zero in your calculations so, no matter what else the data says about temperature, humidity or windspeed, you will not be able to turn `overcast, hot, normal, weak` into a classification prediction of `N`.  This is a feature/bug resulting from a $\text{Beta}(0,0)$ prior, and is probably not a robust approach: among other things it is prone to lead to division by zero with some input data